# AWS IAM autorisation: how to give access to service with aws console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity-management

I have a "root" account.

I created an "admin" account which has all the right.

I created an account "dev" and I want it to only have acces to certain services:
s3
dynamoDB
cloudWatch
API Gateway
Lambda
Cognito

So I created a policy with the aws console editor and I gave full access to theses ressources and allows everything, it gave me this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "apigateway:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "cognito-idp:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks good to me (not specific enough but good for a beginner).

Problem: I created db, lambda, api gateway, etc... but I can't see the services with this, which autorisation should I give for the "dev" role to see the items in the AWS console ?

Comment: Are you sure the dev user is viewing the same region that those resources exist in?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I only needed to switch my region in the top right corner of the console. (shame on me)